# render individual file in middleman

Tags: ruby, middleman

I am writing a helper and I need to get a rendered file as String.

I see that the method that I need exists in the middleman's library: http://rubydoc.info/github/middleman/middleman/Middleman/CoreExtensions/Rendering/InstanceMethods#render_individual_file-instance_method

How do I call this function from my helper class?

I tried:

```
require "middleman-core/lib/middleman-core/core_extensions/rendering.rb"
```

...

```
puts Middleman::CoreExtensions::Rendering::InstanceMethods.render_individual_file(filepath)
```

But it does not seem to find the file, any idea?

Comment: why don't you use the partial method?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure 3.0 beta is quite ready for primetime.

That said, it does sound like the partial method is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, the Middleman method seems like an overly-complex solution. For one of my sites I wanted to load entire text files into my templates, so I wrote this helper:

```
# Shortcut for loading raw text files. Obviously assumes that given file is in a valid format.
# @return [String] File contents
def load_textfile(filename)
  File.read filename.to_s
end
```

**Also**, you *should* clarify if you are intending to use this within a template, or within Ruby code. It's not clear to me based on your question.

Here is an example of how one would use above helper:

1. Currently of note, Middleman is in the process of transitioning to version 4, and the conventions for loading helpers will change. **The most straightforward way to define a helper** is within a `helper` block in your `config.rb` file, as follows:

   ```
   helpers do
     # Define helper functions here to make them available in templates
   end
   ```
2. I use [Slim](http://slim-lang.com/) for templating. It really is the best. In slim you would appply helper as thus:

   ```
   = load_textfile 'path'
   p You can embed helper output in your page with interpolation, too: #{load_textfile 'path'}
   ```